# how to disable horizontal scrolling without my content getting disappeared

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using brackets to make my website responsive. When I decrease the width of my webpage to its minimum size, the user can scroll horizontally so I added `body{overflow x hidden; max-width 100%}`. But this is not working

link to my [webpage](https://www.yousufjawed.com/website)

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue

Comment: You have to properly align your elements in your layout for smaller screens. It seems like the section with your work is not well aligned. See here: https://pasteboard.co/JbtX8gc.png This is what activates your horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: I have set the columns width to 100% also added overflow hidden but it is not working

Comment: This is a problem related to your CSS framework. You should learn how to use it properly in order to solve the given issue. Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not here to solve such a kind of problems :)